# Use of "any more than" to relate two different situations

Tags: phrases, conjunctions, word-usage

In the following quote by Billy Sunday “Going to church doesn’t make you a Christian any more than going to a garage makes you an automobile.” can anyone pls explain/elaborate the usage and meaning of **"any more than"**.

Thank you.

Comment: _Any_: **adverb** in whatever degree; to some extent; at all: Do you feel any better? - in your case: _to any greater degree than_

Comment: @mplungjan I am interested in the origin of this phrase. Closing it does not give an answer, *any more than* snide comments do.

Comment: What snide remarks are you referring to??? And it was closed 3 years ago with a according to me helpful comment.